# We define the subgroup normally generated by S $\subseteq$ G to be the smallest normal subgroup N of G containing S.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that
N=$\left \{ (g_{1}s_{1}^{\epsilon _{1}}g_{1}^{-1})...(g_{k}s_{k}^{\epsilon _{k}}g_{k}^{-1})|s_{i}\in S,g_{i}\in G,\epsilon _{i}\in\left \{ \pm 1 \right \},k\geq 1 \right \}$.

So G is a group. The subgroup generated by S $\subseteq$ G has two equivalent definitions: we may think of it either as the smallest subgroup H of G containing S, or, concretely, as the set
$\left \{ s_{1}^{\epsilon _{1}}...s_{k}^{\epsilon _{k}}|s_{i}\in S, \epsilon _{i}\in\left \{ \pm 1 \right \},k\geq 1 \right \}\leq G$.

What is a good way to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the S in this case? Which two descriptions of N are you trying to prove are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that your set is a normal subgroup of $G$ (containing $S$) because it is trivially closed under both conjugation and the operation of the group.

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $S$, then your set must be contained in it because every such $N$ must necessarily contain:

- every element of $S$ (and its inverse, since $N$ is a subgroup);
- all the conjugates of any such elements;
- every possible (finite) product of the elements obtained so far.

This is nothing more than a description of the set you are considering, and saying it must be contained in every such $N$ means it must be part of their intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I} N_i$.

Comment: Using the same argument as in your item one, can't we say that every power of every element of S is in N and then conclude that actually $N = \{\prod_{i=1}^n x_is_i^{n_i}x_i^{-1} : s_i \in S, x_i \in G, n_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Neglect the case when $S$ is empty, where the convention is that the subgroup generated by the empty set just consists of the identity element.

Any subgroup containing $S$ must contain each element of $S$, and must contain the inverse of every element of $S$, and must be closed under taking products ( so if $S$ is non-empty, must contain the identity element). Hence any subgroup containing $S$ must contain all the terms in the second description.

On the other hand, the elements in the second description are closed under taking inverses and under taking products and conjugation by $G$, (and the set of such is non-empty), so do form a subgroup which contains $S$.